# mapActions with payload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I've a different approach for dispatching an action. There's no click handler anywhere in the component but relies on event hub like below:

```
created() {
  eventHub.$on('eventName', this.onCall)
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions([
    'dispatcher'
  ]),
  onCall() {
    this.dispatcher({
      dataA: this.dataA,
      dataB: this.dataB,
      dataC: this.dataC
    })
  }
}
```

So, you can see `onCall` is called and inside that the dispatcher is called. I would like to know if there's any way use mapActions something like below:

```
created() {
  eventHub.$on('eventName', this.dispatcher)
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions({
    type: 'dispatcher',
    payload: {
      dataA: this.dataA,
      dataB: this.dataB,
      dataC: this.dataC
    }
  })
}
```

But looking at the [api](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#mapactions), I couldn't understand if I can use such like that.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your first approach. That's how I do it. This way you can also turn off the listener if you need to -> eventHub.$off('eventName', this.onCall)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of this as a better approach for this:

```
created() {
  eventHub.$on('eventName', this.onCall)
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions([
    // if there's any other
  ]),
  onCall() {
    this.$store.dispatch('dispatcher',{
      dataA: this.dataA,
      dataB: this.dataB,
      dataC: this.dataC
    })
  }
}
```